# An efficient way to repopulate a select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I've got a good'n'old double select box and was wondering what's the most efficient way to remove all its options and include new ones. This is my current approach (jQuery-less suggestions are also welcomed):

```js
var citiesSelect = $('#cities'),
    cities = ['A bunch', 'Of', 'Cities'], //would come from an external array of AJAX
    option;

citiesSelect.find('option').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});

cities.unshift('---'); //including a blank option
for (i in cities) {
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = i;
    option.innerText = cities[i];
    citiesSelect.append(option);
}
```

## EDIT: RESULTS

[This is the JSPerf that resulted from this question](http://jsperf.com/for-vs-for-in-stack/3) (that's buried into answers' comments).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/empty/, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: Also it's not a good idea to use a `for ... in` loop for JavaScript arrays.

Comment: your entire loop body can be succinctly coded as: citiesSelect.append(new Option(cities[i], i)); and your middle block can be replaced by citiesSelect[0].options.length=0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most efficient ways to add a lot of dom elements at once is to use a document fragment. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

```
var citiesSelect = $('#cities'),
    cities = ['A bunch', 'Of', 'Cities'], //would come from an external array of AJAX
    option,
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

citiesSelect.empty();

cities.unshift('---'); //including a blank option
for (var i = 0;i < cities.length; i++){
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = i;
    option.innerText = cities[i];
    frag.appendChild(option);
}

citiesSelect.append(frag);
```

I also added a test case to [@Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680420/jack)'s jsperf https://stackoverflow.com/users/680420/jack

And here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qzxkw/)

Comment: Good addition. Fragments appear to be the fastest.

Comment: This one sounds exactly like what I was looking for. I though there could be a way to add "a bunch at once" but not sure how :)
Meanwhile, I've added more test cases and mixed this idea with @dandavis's: http://jsperf.com/for-vs-for-in-stack/3

Answer (score 1):

Using the below will net you better efficiency. Here's a fiddle you can fiddle with 
http://jsfiddle.net/NqRrB/. I also create a jsperf that you could add tests too: http://jsperf.com/for-vs-for-in-stack.

```
var citiesSelect = $('#cities'),
    cities = ['A bunch', 'Of', 'Cities'], //would come from an external array of AJAX
    option;

citiesSelect.empty();

cities.unshift('---'); //including a blank option
for (var i = 0;i < cities.length; i++){
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = i;
    option.innerText = cities[i];
    citiesSelect.append(option);
}
```

Comment: +1 for starting up the JSPerf and for the for..in vs for idea :)

Answer (score 1):

this is a little shorter and probably faster to execute:

```
var citiesSelect = $('#cities'),
    cities = ['A bunch', 'Of', 'Cities']; // would come from an external array of AJAX

citiesSelect[0].options.length=0; // clear existing options
cities.unshift('---'); // including a blank option


// populate with new options:
$(cities).each(function(i,v){
  citiesSelect.append(new Option(v, i));
});
```

using the native dom is occasionally simpler and faster than using jQuery.
the *options* collection and *Option()* constructor in particular are great for managing selects.